# How to convert UnicodeString to BSTR?

Tags: c++, string, c++builder, bstr

I'm having a problem when calling OpenDatabase function (DAO). It's prototipe is:

```
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OpenDatabase(BSTR Name/*[in]*/, VARIANT Options/*[in,opt]*/, 
                                             VARIANT ReadOnly/*[in,opt]*/, 
                                             VARIANT Connect/*[in,opt]*/, 
                                             Dao_tlb::Database** ppDb/*[out,retval]*/) = 0; // [-1]
```

So, when I do this:

```
if(OpenDialog1->Execute() != true) return;
```

The selected filename is saved in **OpenDialog1->FileName**. Then I call the function above:

```
    pDatabasePtr = pDBEngine->OpenDatabase(WideString(OpenDialog1->FileName).c_bstr(), myOpts, myRead, myCon);
```

and this works! But, the problem is when I try to set the filename to something else:

```
OpenDialog1->FileName = ParamStr(1); // OpenDatabase don't work in runtime - file not recognised!
```

or even set the filename inside a function:

```
    pDatabasePtr = pDBEngine->OpenDatabase(WideString(L"SomeDB.mdb").c_bstr(), myOpts, myRead, myCon);
```

In both cases I get strange errors and never able to open a database. So, I probably convert UnicodeString/WideString to BSTR incorrectly.

So, why this function (OpenDatabase) works with

```
if(OpenDialog1->Execute() != true) return;
```

and does not work with

```
OpenDialog1->FileName = ParamStr(1);
```

How do I set the conversion correctly?

Comment: how is `OpenDialog1->FileName` declared?

Comment: It is not declared. It is initialized by calling OpenDialog1->Execute().

Comment: but you must have some kind of declaration e.g. function/variable/datatype what not. You attempt to assign to it, so FileName must be a variable then of some kind?

Comment: There is no need for any declaration since Execute() sets the FileName after user selects the file. I'm just trying to bypass Execute and set the FileName to something else - like to ParamStr(1).

Comment: Regardless of what you're trying to do, @claptrap's question still remains: How is `FileName` declared?  It must have a data type.  What is that type?

Comment: You say you have a problem with conversion BSTR and Unicode but you fail to say what type "FileName" is so it is not possible to give you a proper answer. Also consider that Execute may do things behind that scene that are related to "FileName" so setting it to another value may be dicey

Comment: FileName is UnicodeString.

Comment: declared as? wstring? wchar_t* , LPSTR, LPWSTR ... ?

Comment: Don't understand what are you asking me? FileName from OpenDialog is declared as UnicodeString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer in here if anyone else needs it:
https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=498776

Comment: the link is broken.